# Does the code listing in "Practical Reverse Engineering" contain an error, or do I misunderstand loop constructs?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I recently started to learn assembly in order to do reverse engineering. I'm reading [Practical Reverse Engineering](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118787315,subjectCd-CSJ0.html) and saw this assembly code there:

```
loop_start:    
  mov eax, [edi+4]
  mov eax, [eax+ebx*4]
  test eax, eax
  ... //They also did the dots here
  jz short loc_7F627F
loc_7F627F:
  inc ebx
  cmp ebx, [edi]
  jl short loop_start
```

They then told that this info should give us the idea, to decompile it to this (I'm doing all the dots exactly where they did it):

```
typedef struct _Foo
{
  DWORD size;
  DWORD array[...];} FOO, *PFOO;

  PFOO bar= ...;

  for(i= ...; i < bar->size; i++)
  {
    if(bar->array[i] != 0){
    ...
  }
}
```

But as `jz short loc_7F627F` would only jump if the content of eax was zero shouldn't the `...` be after `jz` rather than before `jz`? Otherwise this would mean I test the content of `eax`, whether it is zero, then do some unknown stuff and later jump if it was zero (Provided that no other instruction contained in the `...` is effecting the `ZF` flag), which does not seem to match the C-code they wrote.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The `…` should go after the `jz`. Funny, on the website you linked, there is a link to a form where you can supposedly submit errors, but it uselessly redirects to the home page. :-(

Comment: The book has a large errata list, like most any book has.  Check the list at the [publisher's site](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118787315,subjectCd-CSJ0.html), add yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part:

```
loc_7F627F:
inc ebx
cmp ebx, [edi]
jl short loop_start
```

Translates to:

```
for(i= ?; i < bar->size; i++){
    //do something
    }
}
```

This part

```
mov eax, [edi+4]
mov eax, [eax+ebx*4]
test eax, eax
... //They also did the dots here
jz short loc_7F627F
```

(Does not) translate to:

```
if(bar->array[i] != 0){
  ...
}
```

You are correct.
The `...` should only be executed if `array[i] <> 0` and so the `...` in the assembly statement should be after the `jz skip_to_next_loop_iteration`, not before.

Normally there should also be an unconditional jump to `loc_7F627F` after the `...`; however in this case the code after the first `...` can just fall through to the for loop.